# GeoFire with .net core

Tags: firebase, asp.net-core, .net-core, geofire

I'm converting a small web api from Node.js to .net core. We use Google Firebase for our database. For the new api, I am using FireSharp as my basic library for accessing the db, and I like it a lot.

However, I can't figure out how to access Google's GeoFire library from .net? Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no pre-built Geofire library provided by Firebase for .NET.

But a [quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=geofire+.net) show this [SideGeoFire library](https://github.com/sidesoftware/SideGeoFire) that looks promising.

If that doesn't work for you, consider building your own. The code for Firebase's GeoFire library is open-source, and while it isn't trivial, it's not the hardest code to port either. To learn more about the basics of how Geohashes, GeoFire, and Geoqueries work, have a look at the video of my talk [Querying Firebase and Firestore based on geographic location or distance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q).